# Is it possible to make such a request with extra options in Python?

Tags: python, curl

In a command line I make `curl` requests, that look like so:

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8983:/solr/collection1/update/extract/?literal.id=
any_document_id_you_like&commit=true' -F  'myfile=@path_to_the_file_you_want_to_index'
```

I wonder if it is possible (and if yes, then how - syntax etc.) to make such a request in `Python` code, using some library.

Comment: Look at the requests library  http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: @ user985366 . Thanks, I've heard about this library, The only trouble I see is this extra option `-F ...`. I do not know how to treat it.

Comment: Why are people voting down? If they think, that it is trivial thing to do, why not to share first?

Comment: Just 1 downvote as far as I can see. I think a person could be motivated to vote down because it looks like you would find what you need if you google "python curl" and/or "python request"; the question did not show even a minimal search effort.

Comment: It is absolutely trivial to make  post and get requests in Python. Everybody knows it. But what I'm asking seams to be non-trivial case, since from curl documentation `-F lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button`. But how this theory traverses to Python code?

Comment: Then perhaps you should rephrase the question title and text to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the subprocess module like this:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['curl', myLink, '-F', myFile])
```

or if you need the output

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(['curl', myLink, '-F', myFile])
```

and to be complete:

```
myLink = 'http://127.0.0.1:8983:/solr/collection1/update/extract/?literal.id=any_document_id_you_like&commit=true'
myfile = 'myfile=@path_to_the_file_you_want_to_index'
```

Comment: Can you, please, specify what `myLink` and `myFile` values should be in the context of my example?

Comment: Thank you, sir! +100500 for your brilliant knowledge!

Comment: And btw, don't you know, why python `requests` and `pycurl` do not support such functionality? Is there something extremely special about options like `-F` etc?